# MySQL Crashed Table Unable to save result set

Tags: mysql, crash, resultset

I have a crashed table which I am unsure how to repair with. Here is the dump of my error trace:

```
Warning: mysql_query(): Unable to save result set in 
    C:\Users\programmer\workspace\DBMigration\functions.php 
    on line 10 MySQL Query Failed! 1194: Table 'exp_weblog_titles' is marked as 
    crashed and should be repaired
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is MyISAM table:

1. make backup of exp_weblog_titles.* files
2. copy exp_weblog_titles.MYD and exp_weblog_titles.MYI to D:\work or any working directory
3. run  myisamchk D:\work\exp_weblog_titles --repair
4. on success you may copy table back to mysql data directory
5. on failure - you will get different problem

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem similar to your. REPAIR command help me in my case - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/repair-table.html